# PWA 2013: How to add a column to the project scheduler?

Tags: project-server, ms-project

If this has been answered before, I apologize. I've been googling this topic for a few hours now and have come up with nothing, so maybe I'm just misunderstanding something fundamental with MS Project... anyway here goes:

In Project Pro 2010/2013, it's fairly straightforward to add a new column to your new task (see pic below).
[image: 'Add New Column' option]

However, in PWA 2013, I can not figure out how to add a basic column (like "Predecessors"). There's nothing in the ribbon. No options for adding columns in the "Configure Column" menu. And I've scoured through PWA Settings and Site Settings to no avail.
[image: No option?!]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screen shot, take note of the name of the current view you're on: "Tasks Summary" (it's in a dropdown towards the right side of the ribbon). Then:

1. go to the gear icon in the upper right --> PWA settings --> Manage Views
2. Scroll down, find and click on "Tasks Summary"
3. In the "table and fields" section, add or rearrange fields as needed.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much, sir. I love how intuitive PWA is. it's great.